# Why am I getting a 'Cannot find resource named 'GUIDConverter'' error when running my XAML program?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have an Xaml page that uses a binding convert to convert a GUID to a string however when running the program I get the following error:

```
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'GUIDConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive.
```

I have the IValueConverter interface as

```
public class GUIDConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string? strGuid;
            try
            {
                strGuid = value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
                throw;
            }
            
            return strGuid;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Guid? OldGuid;
            try
            {
                OldGuid = Guid.Parse(value.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Guid.Empty;
            }
            return OldGuid;
        }
    }
```

and referencing it in the App.Xaml as:

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:super="clr-namespace:DatabaseTest">
    <Application.Resources>
        <super:GUIDConverter x:Key="GUIDConverter"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and finally, I added the converter like so:

```
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElementName=customerID, Converter={StaticResource GUIDConverter}, ConverterParameter=Normal}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding firstName}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
```

I'm not really sure why this isn't working as it seems to be written the correct way, I'd appreciate any help

(Also, I am using Mah:Metro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the reference in a `ResourceDictionary` if you want to make it accessible in the `StaticStaticResources` like this:

```xml
<Application ...
    xmlns:super="clr-namespace:DatabaseTest">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <super:GUIDConverter x:Key="GUIDConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Or if you need it only in the place you're using the `ListView` you can insert the reference in the `Window.Resources`